# Some index files failed to download

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, software-center, sudo

When I ran `sudo apt-get update` then I found some error. The Error is like below:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)/dists/raring/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Could anyone please help me why I am getting this kind error message? I've just found the Error message today on my machine

Comment: Just `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and remove/comment the lines that contain `cdrom`. It would be advisable to show us the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also copy and paste this command into the terminal (ctrl+alt+t) to open the terminal, then paste:

```
gksu software-properties-gtk
```

a window will open type in your user password then uncheck the CD-ROM boxes under the 'Other Software' tab. Close the program when you're done, and it should prompt you to reload the sources lists do that and it should work.